# Prevent encoding of Cypher query POSTed via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, content-type

I have a Cypher query for Neo4j which looks like this:

```
var query = "MATCH (t:Person {name: 'Darth Vader'})-[:CHILD_OF*0..1]-child RETURN <a bunch of node properties>"

        $.ajax({
            url: '/wdc/query',
            type: 'post',
            data: query,
            contentType: 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Said query is POSTed to a route in a node.js app where it is executed against Neo4j. The body of the POST which I received is handled like so:

```
app.post('/wdc/query', function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

I can't seem to pick the correct contentType in order to avoid my string from getting heavily munged:

```
//contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
{ 'MATCH (t:Person {name: \'Darth Vader\'})-': { ':CHILD_OF*0..1': '' } }

//contentType: 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8'"
{}

//contentType: 'text/x-java-source,java; charset=UTF-8'
{}

//contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
 Error: invalid json
```

I'm clearly shooting blanks here. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction? Do I just need to encode this whole damn string and be done with it? (unfortunately, some of the methods I see to do this don't handle characters like `'['`)

Thanks.

**Edit**

**Never Mind** Just used JSON to wrap the query and then passed that as JSON/application. Works well - only thing that happens is we escape the single quotes around "Darth Vader", which is expected:

```
var jsonObj={};
            jsonObj["statement"] = match + returnClause;
            query = JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
```